# GZIP not working with Protocol Buffer. Snappy does

Tags: java, gzip, protocol-buffers

I am learning Protocol Buffer in Java. After basic serialization/deserialization, I am attempting to put compression. 
In the provided code, I tried to use GZIP but while deserializing, it reads one extra record. It can be seen in System.out printing an extra "," at end.
This problem does not happen when using same code, but with Snappy (Commented in code below). Any suggestions if I am doing something wrong? Or if I can bypass the problem.

Output with GZIP:

```
id0,NAME0
,
```

Output with Snappy:

```
id0,NAME0
```

Code:

```
package testPkg;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;

import org.xerial.snappy.SnappyInputStream;
import org.xerial.snappy.SnappyOutputStream;

public class TestProtoBuf {

public static String fileNm = "C:/testFile";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // creating data
    List<DataClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        list.add(new DataClass("id" + i, "NAME" + i));
    }
    // writing data
    try (OutputStream os = new GZIPOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileNm)))
    /*OutputStream os = new SnappyOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileNm)))*/) {
        for (DataClass dc : list) {
            DataClassProtoBufProxy.DataClass.Builder bld = DataClassProtoBufProxy.DataClass.newBuilder();
            bld.setId(dc.id);
            bld.setName(dc.name);
            bld.build().writeDelimitedTo(os);
        }
        os.flush();
    }
    // reading data
    try (InputStream is = new GZIPInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileNm)))
    /*InputStream is = new SnappyInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileNm)))*/) {
        while (is.available() > 0) {
            DataClassProtoBufProxy.DataClass.Builder bld = DataClassProtoBufProxy.DataClass.newBuilder();
            bld.mergeDelimitedFrom(is);
            DataClassProtoBufProxy.DataClass dc = bld.build();
            System.out.println(dc.getId() + "," + dc.getName());
        }
    }
}

static class DataClass {
    private String id;
    private String name;

    DataClass() {
        id = null;
        name = null;
    }

    DataClass(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

}

The proto file:

```
// [START declaration]
syntax = "proto3";
package testPkg;
// [END declaration]

// [START java_declaration]
option java_package = "testPkg";
option java_outer_classname = "DataClassProtoBufProxy";
// [END java_declaration]

// [START messages]
message DataClass {
  string id = 1;
  string name = 20;
}
// [END messages]
```

Maven dependencies:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
    <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial.snappy/snappy-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xerial.snappy</groupId>
    <artifactId>snappy-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Have you figured this out? It is strange, that you do not get an exception at `bld.mergeDelimitedFrom(is);`, but you get an empty DataClass object instead.

Comment: Sorry.. have sort of moved away from it for now.. until it comes later..